# MYSQli select not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am not actually very good at it, but I never got this kind of error. I am trying to select GB entries and I can't get it working.

**gb.php**

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','ab','somepassword','gb');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}
else {echo 'connected';}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts`";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo 'done';
 }
else{echo 'sql not working';}

?>
```

**Table snapshot**
[image: screenshot of sql table]

**Result:**

```
connectedsql not working
```

One more thing the INSERT & UPDATE statements are working from same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of MySqlI->query() is defined like:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So you must check for not equal to false

```
if ($result !== false) {
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query`/ `$mysqli->query` does not return `True` if the query executed succesfully but return `false` if not executed..Try with -

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result !== false) {
echo 'done';
 }
else{echo 'sql not working';}
```

Comment: @markus was a bit fast, your solution is also pretty.

Answer (score 1):

you can also check on this condition

```
$res=$conn->query($sql);
    if($res)
    {
    }
    else
    {

    }
```